# Can Azure Internal Loadbalancer have backends belonging to different subnets in the VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

1.Confused about what the below options refer to, is my understanding correct?
[WHat does vnet and subnet refer to while creating Internal LB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7ePg.png)

2.In summary, does VNET refer to where the internal lB resides and front end of LB receives traffic from this VNET.
And does 'Subnet' refer to backend pool of VMs?

2b.This makes me assume even if we have multiple backend pools, they need to belong to same subnet?

3.Further, for public LB, frontend can receive traffic from Internet but the multiple backend pools need to belong to single vnet ?

4.( making me think that the Public LB actually belongs to a vnet though there is no explicit tieing to vnet like done Internal LB)?
The only place where we mention vnet in case of Public LB is while defining backend pool:
[Public LB--no explicit VNET association except when defining backend pools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhgn.png)

Answer (score 0):

A1. All things are right, except that you think the VNet is the frontend. It's also the backend of the Load Balancer. Only the private IP address is the frontend when you create a private Load Balancer.

A2. The VNet is the backend that the traffic will arrive. All the subnets should be in the VNet, and the endpoint like the VM must in the subnet. The frontend receives the traffic outside the Load Balancer.

A3. All the backends of the LB should be in the same VNet. You get the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/backend-pool-management#configure-backend-pool-by-ip-address-and-virtual-network) for the Backend.

A4. The public IP address only belongs to the LB, not the VNet when the LB is public. And the LB does not belong to a VNet, it just like a router and it's in front of the VNet.

Comment: Thanks Charles for your kind response.
So to summarize 2b. If we have multiple backend pools for an Internal LB then they all need to belong to same subnet right?
(The 'subnet' option described in 1)

Kind regards.
Aditya

Comment: @AdityaGarg It's the same VNet, not the subnet, subnets just like children of the VNet.

Comment: @AdityaGarg If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: @AdityaGarg Any updates on this issue? Does it work for you? If it solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks Charles, however,I only see an option to choose single subnet while defining 'Internal LB'.This seems to imply that indeed the backends,if multiple, all need to be in same SUBNET!

Comment: @AdityaGarg Of course, I already gave the limitation in the answer. See the A3.